# Knockout databind reset

Tags: knockout.js

I use knockout databinds on webforms.  Currently I have a reset function that is used before re-loading original data to clear the form.  I have over 60 fields that I need to clear and doing each one individual is a pain. Is there a way to clear all knockout bindings at once?  Currently what I use is below:

```
self.parentObject.somefield('');
self.parentObjectAddress.street1('');
etc 
etc
```

-- Update 1--

To add clarification all my fields are part of a parentObject.  Example

```
self.parentObject.fieldName
```

What I am looking to do is clear all children of the parentObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider a different approach. Rather than "resetting" the object itself, why not create a new object, and throw the old one away? You should already have code to create the object. If you have a `data-bind="with: someObject"` at the top level (maybe the `<form>` tag?) then replace someObject (assuming it's observable) with a new, "clean" instance of the object.

Comment: This requires a whole different way of thinking from what I was doing before, but does the trick very well.